# How to retrieve custom fileld values from magento 2

Tags: magento2, module

I have added some custom fields to the admin->configurations->sales->payment section using the following method.

created config.xml inside `etc` folder of my module dir.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <payment>
        <ProductSpecificPayments>
            <model>Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier\ProductSpecificPayments</model>
            <name>Product Specific Payment</name>
        </ProductSpecificPayments>
    </payment>
</default>
```

Then created system.xml in `adminhtml` folder.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <section id="payment">
        <group id="productspecific" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="500" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Productspecific Payment Configuration</label>
            <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Enabled</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Title</label>
            </field>
            <field id="name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Name</label>
            </field>
            <field id="allowed_shippings" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Allowed Payment Methods</label>
                <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\AllPayements</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="highes_amount" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Fallback Payment</label>
                <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\AllPayements</source_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

now it is working fine. but How I can retrieve these saved values in product adding a page or any other files?

especialy inside a Model.

Comment: what should i use instead of SCOPE_STORES?

Comment: You can use the SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT and SCOPE_STORES in the $storeScope. SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT for getting default view configuration while SCOPE_STORES is for getting store views settings. Check my answer for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the value of the system.xml fields in your block, model, controller by adding the below code in them.

```
protected $_scopeConfig;

public function __construct( 
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
) 
{
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

public function getYourValue() {
    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES;
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue("section_id/group_id/field_id", $storeScope); //where section_id, group_id and field_id defined in your system.xml file
}
```

You can use the `SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT` and `SCOPE_STORES` in the `$storeScope`. `SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT` is for getting default view configuration setting while `SCOPE_STORES` is for getting store views configuration setting.

**Hope it helps!!!**

Answer (score 1):

**Hope below code will help you :**

```
namespace Company\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{

    const XML_PATH_HELLOWORLD = 'helloworld/';

    public function getConfigValue($field, $storeId = null)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $field, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId
        );
    }

    public function getGeneralConfig($code, $storeId = null)
    {

        return $this->getConfigValue(self::XML_PATH_HELLOWORLD .'general/'. $code, $storeId);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
) {
    parent::__construct($scopeConfig);
}
```

And get the config value:

```
public function getTitle()
{
    $title = $this->getConfigData('title');
    return $title;
}
```